# How to calculate monthly changes as a percentage in Pycharm

Tags: python, import, pycharm, percentage

I’m finding it hard to calculate the monthly changes as a percentage from a spreadsheet (CSV file) in pycharm. I’m unsure on the functions to use.
I’ve tried to import the CSV file and it’s unable to locate it.

```
import csv
with open("sales.csv", "r") as csvfile:
  csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(‘sales.csv’)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It’s saying unable to locate the file. Even with the new changes.